# parse cloud delete row through cloud job

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I am writing a parse Cloud job which first checks for the best score. And then deletes rows for two tables. The best score part works properly but it doesn't delete the rows from the tables. I don't know what's wrong with the code.

```
var deletePrizes = new Parse.Query("Prizes");
                deletePrizes.equalTo("contestId",contestId);

                return deletePrizes.find({
                    success: function(results){
                        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                        {
                            var result = results[i];
                            result.destroy({});
                            console.log("Destroy: " + result);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){}
                });

                var deleteContests = new Parse.Query("PrizeTypes");
                deleteContests.equalTo("contestId",contestId);

                return deleteContests.find({
                    success: function(results){
                        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                        {
                            var result = results[i];
                            result.destroy({});
                            console.log("Destroy: " + result);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){}
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use master key to delete the object from parse.

just add the below code when you are destroying the object.

```
result.destroy({
    useMasterKey: true ,
    success:function() {
      console.log("Successfully deleted"+result);

    },
    error:function(error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong "+error);

    }
});
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for this. But it still isn't getting deleted. I am also not getting any log. I am not sure but it's probably because the queries are inside another query.